# How would you go about nesting structs?

Tags: c++, struct

Here is an example:

```
struct colorRGB {

    float r, g, b;

    colorHSV toHSV()
    {
        colorHSV hsv;
        // some code..
        return hsv;
    }
};

struct colorHSV {

    float h, s, v;

    colorRGB toRGB()
    {
        colorRGB rgb;
        // some code..
        return rgb;
    }
};
```

colorRGB won't work since it doesn't know about colorHSV yet.
So how can I make something like this to work?

Comment: not everything has to be a member function. If you declare `toHSV` and `toRGB` as free functions you dont have the problem, still those would be considered as part of the interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forward-declare `struct colorHSV;` and provide the definition of the member function `colorRGB::toHSV()` only after the type `colorHSV` is complete, i.e. known by the compiler.

```
// Forward-declare return type of toHsv() member function:
struct colorHSV;

struct colorRGB {
    float r, g, b;
    colorHSV toHSV();
};

struct colorHSV { /* Same as in your snippet. */ };

// Now that colorHSV is defined, we can implement the function using it:
colorHSV colorRGB::toHSV()
{
   colorHSV hsv;
   // some code..
   return hsv;
}
```